# Passing EL method expression as attribute of custom Facelets tagfile

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, tagfile, methodexpression

I created a custom JSF tag:

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <rich:dataScroller id="#{id}" for="#{table}" execute="#{table}"
            page="#{scrollerPage}" render="#{table}-sc1" maxPages="5"
            fastControls="hide" oncomplete="#{onCompl}" scrollListener="#{scrollListenerBean[scrollListenerMethod]}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{scrollerPage}" id="#{table}-sc1" size="2">
            <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputText styleClass="outputText"
            value=" of #{scrollPagesCount}  " />
        <h:commandButton value="GO! " />
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

To pass the listener method, I used the solution suggested in a quite old [blog](http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2009/08/25/passing-action-methods-in-facelets-using-array-notation/):

```
<my:dataScroller id="idDS1" table="table1"
                    scrollerPage="#{bean.navigationHelper.scrollerPage}"
                    scrollPagesCount="#{bean.navigationHelper.scrollPagesCount}"
                    onCompl="initForm();" 
                    scrollListenerBean="#{bean}"
                    scrollListenerMethod="aMethod" />
```

My questions are: is this the best way to do this? How can I make the method optional?

Thanks a lot for any Help! bye!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *My questions are: is this the best way to do this?*

That's the *only* way anyway, provided that you can only use standard JSF/EL facilities and you cannot create a custom taghandler.

You could however create a custom taghandler to convert the value expression to a method expression. The [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) JSF utility library has a `<o:methodParam>` for exactly this purpose. See also [the `<o:methodParam>` demo page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/methodParam).

You could then end up like:

```
<my:dataScroller ... scrollListener="#{bean.aMethod}" />
```

and

```
<o:methodParam name="scrollListenerMethod" value="#{scrollListener}" />
<rich:dataScroller ... scrollListener="#{scrollListenerMethod}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Dynamic ui include and commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002272/dynamic-ui-include-and-commandbutton/)

---

> *How can I make the method optional?*

Theoretically, you could use JSTL tags to build the view conditionally. Something like:

```
<h:someComponent>
    <c:if test="#{not empty fooAttribute}">
        <f:attribute name="foo" value="#{fooAttriubte}" />
    </c:if>
</h:someComponent>
```

But that's in the particular case of a special method expression listener attribute unfortunately not possible. There's no such thing as `<rich:scrollListener>` or something which allows you binding a RichFaces specific `scrollListener` as a separate tag to the `<rich:dataScroller>`. Best what you could do without creating custom taghandlers is duplicating the whole `<rich:dataScroller>` in two `<c:if>`s (or a `<c:choose>`); one with and other without `scrollListener`. This is too clumsy. You'd really better create a custom `<my:richScrollListener>` taghandler for this which you could then place in a `<c:if>`.