# Dynamic ui include and commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton, uiinclude

I have a page which includes content from another page dynamically (this is done by a method in the bean)

**firstPage.xhtml**

```
<ui:include src="#{managedBean.pageView}">
    <ui:param name="method" value="#{managedBean.someAction}"/>
</ui:include>
```

This redirects to a secondPage which is within `<ui:composition>` which has commandButton.

**secondPage.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition>
..
..
<p:commandButton actionListener=#{method} value="Submit"/>
</ui:composition>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
public String pageView(){
return "secondPage.xhtml";
}

public void someAction(){
*someAction*
}
```

The commandButton in the secondPage.xhtml is not working.

Any help shall be much appreciated.

Comment: Try the `actionListener` attribute instead of `action`.  Action methods require a return value that can be converted to a String.

Comment: yes, i tried that too, and it dint work..

Comment: Action methods can perfectly return `void`. This is treated the same as a `null` return value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't pass method expressions via `<ui:param>`. They're interpreted as value expression.

You've basically 3 options:

1. Split the bean instance and the method name over 2 parameters:

   ```
   <ui:param name="bean" value="#{managedBean}" />
   <ui:param name="method" value="someAction" />
   ```

   And couple them in the tag file using brace notation `[]` as follows:

   ```
   <p:commandButton action="#{bean[method]}" value="Submit" />
   ```

   ---
2. Create a tag handler which converts a value expression to a method expression. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a [`<o:methodParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/methodParam) which does that. Use it as follows in the tag file:

   ```
   <o:methodParam name="action" value="#{method}" />
   <p:commandButton action="#{action}" value="Submit" />
   ```

   ---
3. Use a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) instead. You can use `<cc:attribute method-signature>` to define action methods as attributes.

   ```
   <cc:interface>
       <cc:attribute name="method" method-signature="void method()"/>
   </cc:interface>
   <cc:implementation>
       <p:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.method}" value="Submit"/>
   </cc:implementation>
   ```

   Which is used as follows:

   ```
   <my:button method="#{managedBean.someAction}" />
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry, the method was actionListener. And since I'm forced to use primefaces, I don't have a choice of using omnifaces. Any other choices or options, please?

Comment: Just change `action` in answer by `actionListener` it you really need to? Why do you think that PrimeFaces and OmniFaces can't be used together? OmniFaces is an utility library, not a component library like PrimeFaces/RichFaces. Even more, the OmniFaces showcase application uses PrimeFaces for UI. Note that I mentioned 3 options, of which 2 don't use OmniFaces. Also note that OmniFaces is open source under Apache License.

Comment: `@balus` Is it that, when a bean's method is mentioned inside the src of `<ui:include>` then that method is always called before other methods (when rendering a page)?

Comment: @@balusC Sadly, I have tried them, I cant still access the method in my actionListoner. Am I committing a basic mistake? Please help.