# Generic URL using template on action jsf

Tags: jsf, action, facelets

I created a template with commandLink:

```
<div class="pull-right" style="padding: 5px">
    <h:commandLink action="#{urlVoltar}" styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-reply"></span></h:commandLink>
</div>
```

And use it in main page:

```
<ui:include src="/sistema/commonBotoesExportar.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="urlVoltar" value="\indexNovo.xhtml" />
</ui:include>
```

So when I click on button, I got this exception:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: //C:/project/WebContent/sistema/commonBotoesExportar.xhtml @13,154 action="#{urlVoltar}": Identity 'urlVoltar' does not reference a MethodExpression instance, returned type: java.lang.String
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
...
```

What I need to do to solve this issue. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does in first place not make any sense to use `<h:commandLink>` for page-to-page navigation. It would only destroy the SEO and UX of the webpage.

Just use `<h:link>`.

```
<h:link outcome="#{urlVoltar}" ...>
```

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one)

---

If you would *really* like to use a `<h:commandXxx>` component in this construct, then head to this duplicate question: [Dynamic ui include and commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002272/dynamic-ui-include-and-commandbutton/).