# Evaluate EL expression from string as bean in JSF page

Tags: jsf, el

I am fairly new to JSF and am currently a frontend developer for a new project. I do not have access to the backend code and need to create a solution with the data I have access to on the page.

Currently I have a menu and there are security controllers on HTML elements to control visibility.

Example:
style="#{security.ConfigMenu?'visibility:visible':'visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;padding-bottom: 0px;'}"

This page is hardcoded and need to make it more dynamic.

I need to evaluate this expression but use an array of beans stored as strings

var security = ["security.ConfigMenu", "security.AdminMenu", "security.Dashboardmenu"];

Need to handle #{mappSec.insightsConfigMenu'} with #{security[0]}

Is this possible?

I tried to replace the bean call with a string using the bean name

#{bean.method}

with

var bean = "bean.method";
#{bean}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically call method in EL, which is evaluated from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239644/dynamically-call-method-in-el-which-is-evaluated-from-a-string)

Comment: No, this does not work but thank you. I need to have a string which represents a bean and a beans method call to be interpreted as such. I am not sure if this is possible

Comment: I figured out the issue. If you make your variable = to the call then it will work. For example: var bean = "#{mybean.IsThisGood}"; What doesn't work is building the variable like var bean = "#{" + "mybean.IsThisGood"+ "}";